# Notwendigkeit von "von" in "nicht von ... sondern von ..."

Tags: grammar, preposition

> (a) Ich bin nicht von meinem Vater abhängig, sondern von meiner Mutter.
>
> (b) Ich bin nicht von meinem Vater abhängig, sondern meiner Mutter.
>
> (c) Ich bin nicht von meinem Vater, sondern von meiner Mutter, abhängig.
>
> (d) Ich bin nicht von meinem Vater, sondern meiner Mutter, abhängig.

Satz (a) ist ein klassisches Beispiel von der Konstruktion "nicht von ... sondern von ...". Kann man das zweite "von" weglassen wie im Satz (b)?

Ändert sich etwas daran, wenn der Teil "sondern ..." vorgeschoben wird wie in (c) und (d)? Sind beide grammatikalisch richtig?

Comment: (b) und (d) klingen für mich definitiv falsch, ich kann aber spontan keine Regel dafür zitieren.

Comment: Bin mir ziemlich sicher, daß es neulich schon einmal um dieses Thema ging, kann aber die alte Frage nicht finden.

Comment: (b) kommt mir falsch vor. Die anderen drei würde ich auf jeden Fall als richtig ansehen. Allerdings scheinen mir alle Kommas in (c) und (d) falsch oder zumindest optional und ungewöhnlich zu sein.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sofern keine Missverständnisse entstehen können, braucht laut Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* die gleiche Präposition nur einmal gesetzt zu werden, wenn sie vor zwei oder mehreren nebengeordneten Substantiven steht.

> Ich bin von meinem Vater und [von] meiner Mutter abhängig.

Jedoch wird bei Substantiven und Pronomen, die durch mehrteilige Konjunktionen verbunden sind, im Allgemeinen die Präposition nicht weggelassen.

> Ich bin *sowohl* von meinem Vater *als auch* von meiner Mutter abhängig.
>
> Ich bin *weder* von meinem Vater *noch* von meiner Mutter abhängig.
>
> Ich bin *nicht* von meinem Vater, *sondern* von meiner Mutter abhängig.
>
> Ich bin *nicht nur* von meinem Vater, *sondern auch* von meiner Mutter abhängig.

Comment: "Ich bin weder von meinem Vater noch von meiner Mutter abhängig." Ist hier "Ich bin weder von meinem Vater noch meiner Mutter abhängig" tatsächlich unschön? Mir missfällt die Wortwiederholung mehr.